# Testcontainers throws ContainerLaunchException for timeout on MySQL 8.2 startup (failed log-matching)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

## TL;DR

Java Spring Boot with Junit Jupiter Test throws on startup:

- java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

  - Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException

    - org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException:

      - Timed out waiting for log output matching '.*(database system is ready to accept connections).*'

MySQL started properly, but testcontainers failed to parse for a matching string.

How to alter the detection?

---

## Setup

### Tech-Stack

- Java: 21
- Spring Boot: 3.0.x
- Testcontainers: 1.19.x
- MySQL: 8.2.x

### Compose

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  # MySQL
  database:
    image: mysql:8.2
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: sampleRootPassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: sampledatabase
      MYSQL_USER: identity
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: identityPassword
    expose:
      - 3306
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./config/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - services_default

volumes:
  mysql-data:
networks:
  services_default:
```

### Simple 'SpringBoot ApplicationTest'

```java
package de.whatever.endpoint;

import de.whatever.testcontainers.DockerCompose;
import de.whatever.testcontainers.Service;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.util.TestPropertyValues;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.testcontainers.containers.DockerComposeContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.POST;

@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        properties = "spring.profiles.active=integrationtest"
)
@Testcontainers
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {EndpointApplicationTest.Initializer.class})
class EndpointApplicationTest {

    private static final Logger logger =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(EndpointApplicationTest.class);
    public static DockerComposeContainer<?> dcEnv;

    @Test
    public void SampleTest() {
        logger.info("Hello World");
        int random = (int)(Math.random()*1000);
        assertTrue(random > -1);
        assertTrue(random < 1001);
    }

    static {
        dcEnv = DockerCompose.createEnvironment(logger);
        dcEnv.start();
    }

    static class Initializer
            implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {

            int port = DockerCompose.getServicePort(dcEnv, Service.DATABASE);

            logger.info(String.format("--- MySQL[%s] ---", port));

            String jdbc = String.format(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:%s/identity?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&currentSchema=sampledatabase",
                    port
            );

            TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + jdbc
            ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
        }
    }

}
```

## Running

Console Output (excerpt):

```
... .. .

09:55:37.577 [docker-java-stream-138462075] INFO de.slr.kbaas.identityservice.authendpoint.AuthEndpointApplicationTest - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.576080Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
09:55:37.578 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.576080Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "117[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0]c2023-12-13T08:55:37.694592Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.[\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xffffffa4]2023-12-13T08:55:37.694612Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.[\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-2 << "117[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-2 << "[0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0]c2023-12-13T08:55:37.694592Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.[\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-2 << "[0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xffffffa4]2023-12-13T08:55:37.694612Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.[\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-2 << "[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] INFO de.slr.kbaas.identityservice.authendpoint.AuthEndpointApplicationTest - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.694592Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] INFO de.slr.kbaas.identityservice.authendpoint.AuthEndpointApplicationTest - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.694612Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-2 << "db[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "db[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-2 << "[0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xffffffd3]2023-12-13T08:55:37.695474Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.[\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xffffffd3]2023-12-13T08:55:37.695474Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.[\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-2 << "[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.695 [docker-java-stream-138462075] INFO de.slr.kbaas.identityservice.authendpoint.AuthEndpointApplicationTest - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.695474Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
09:55:37.701 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-2 << "178[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.701 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "178[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.702 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-2 << "[0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xffffffa0]2023-12-13T08:55:37.701605Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock[\n]"
09:55:37.702 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xffffffa0]2023-12-13T08:55:37.701605Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock[\n]"
09:55:37.702 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-2 << "[0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xffffffc8]2023-12-13T08:55:37.701652Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.2.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.[\n]"
09:55:37.702 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xffffffc8]2023-12-13T08:55:37.701652Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.2.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.[\n]"
09:55:37.702 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-2 << "[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.702 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[\r][\n]"
09:55:37.702 [docker-java-stream-138462075] INFO de.slr.kbaas.identityservice.authendpoint.AuthEndpointApplicationTest - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.701605Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
09:55:37.702 [docker-java-stream-138462075] INFO de.slr.kbaas.identityservice.authendpoint.AuthEndpointApplicationTest - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.701652Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.2.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
09:55:37.703 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.701652Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.2.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
09:55:37.703 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.701605Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
09:55:37.703 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.695474Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
09:55:37.703 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.694612Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
09:55:37.703 [ducttape-0] DEBUG org.testcontainers.containers.output.WaitingConsumer - STDERR: 2023-12-13T08:55:37.694592Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.



09:56:34.703 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000001C: cancel
09:56:34.704 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-1: close connection IMMEDIATE
09:56:34.704 [docker-java-stream-138462075] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-1 << "[read] I/O error: null"
09:56:34.704 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000001C: endpoint closed
09:56:34.704 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient - ep-0000001C: discarding endpoint
09:56:34.704 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000001C: releasing endpoint
09:56:34.704 [ducttape-0] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - ep-0000001C: connection is not kept alive

. .. ...
```

### The Error

From the beginning, Testcontainers tried to detect the finalization of the MySQL database, which happened at `09:55:37.703`

```
[Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.2.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Between 09:55:37.703 and 09:56:34.703 there were no additional logs created.

Finally the startup failed:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out
> waiting for log output matching '.*(database system is ready to
> accept connections).*'

### Log-Scrolling

I assume that testcontainers just uses a wrong log-string match.
Sadly, I do not know how to alter the String.

Moreover the same log-line:

> [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.2.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

... is given multiple times in `09:55:37.702`.

The same applies to the following log-line:

```
[Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
```

I guess both will cause no damage if they are applied. Still the port is needed to be adjusted throughout, as the log-line is given before using `port 0`.

### Final Thoughts

- Is there any chance to adjust the testcontainer string matching for the `wait`?

Likewise:

- How to alter the detection?

Comment: Have you read and tried [Waiting for containers to start or be ready](https://java.testcontainers.org/features/startup_and_waits/) (specifically [Log output Wait Strategy](https://java.testcontainers.org/features/startup_and_waits/#log-output-wait-strategy))?

Comment: That said, given you have a custom MySQL container defined in your docker-compose, are you sure you're trying to use Testcontainers to launch MySQL?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel .. I was far in my tunnel - I guess 'Log output Wait Strategy' from the docs will help figuring this out.   :)
Thanks anyways

Comment: You're welcome. To be honest, I'm not 100% sure this is the right thing, and I currently don't have time to experiment, but I hope it helps you solve the problem (and if it does, pay it forward by answering your own question!)

Comment: As always   :D ..
Sometimes writing the question to stackoverflow is already part of my 'rubberduck-development'   ;-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Things you need

- docker-compose.yml
- dependencies in your POM.xml
- setup java classes

##### The docker-compose.yml

Just as 'in the question'.

##### Dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

#### Setup Java classes

- Spring Boot ApplicationTest

  - Just as 'in the question'
- Function customized for the database specific output

```java
public String mySQLstartLogMessage = "X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060";
public GenericContainer containerWithLogWait = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mysql:8.2"))
        .withExposedPorts(3306)
        .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".*" + mySQLstartLogMessage + ".*\\n", 1));
```